# how to automatically refresh a function on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following function thats loaded onto a page as follows:

```
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

var Methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            return this.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                if (!$this.attr('init')) {
                    var tabs = $this.find('li[type]');
                    $this.attr('init', true);
                    tabs.each(function (index) {
                        $tab = $(this);
                        var $content = $('<div class="Content ' + $tab.attr('type') + '"></div>');
                        $this.append($content);
                        if (index === 0) {
                            $tab.addClass('first');
                            Methods.loadContent($tab);
                        }
                    });
                    $this.on('click.div', 'li[type]', Clicked); //when i click on the div it automatically reloads the function

                }
            });
        },
loadContent: function ($tab) {
          //i do stuff in here
        }
    };


})(jQuery, window, document);
```

when i click on the div i can reload the "loadContent" function as follows:

```
 Clicked: function (event) {
            $target = $(event.currentTarget);
            Methods.loadContent($target);
        },
```

my question is how would i refresh the loadcontent function every 30 seconds automatically with out having to click on the div?

i tried

`setInterval(Methods.init, 30000);` and `setInterval(Methods.loadContent, 30000);` both requests fails and i get a uncaught exception thrown " this.each is not a function
    at init"

Comment: Please provide the details of the exception thrown. It's likely because you're calling the methods with no arguments, in which case you want to call them like `setInterval(() => Methods.init(options), 30000)` or whatever. Note that using `this` in `Methods.init` may also be causing issues for different reasons.

Comment: @HereticMonkey i tried the above and now it says "options is not defined"

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to pass whatever options you would normally pass to `init` there. You've not shown how you usually call `init` so I can only guess and show an example.